# Cannot switch to a frame

Tags: python, selenium, frames

I am  having super difficulty understanding a problem I have while working on automating a page using Chromedriver. I am in the login page and here is how the HTML for the page looks:

```
<frame name="mainFrame" src>
  <body>
    <table ..>
      <tr>
       <td ..>
        <input type="password" name="ui_pws">
       </td>
  ..
  ..
  ..
</frame>
```

This is gist, the page of course has multiple tables, divs, etc ...
I am trying to enter the password in the input element using xpath //input[@name="ui_pws"].
But the element was not found.

So I thought it might be because of wrong frame and I tried:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('mainFrame')
```

and it failed with NoSuchFrameException.
So I switched to:

```
    main_frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//frame[@name="mainFrame"]')
    driver.switch_to_frame(main_frame)
```

Then to cross verify I got the current frame element using:

```
    current_frame = driver.execute_script("return window.frameElement")
```

And to my surprise I got two different elements when printed it out. 
Now I am really confused as to what I should be doing to switch frames or access the password field in the webpage. I have had 4 cups of coffee since morning and still have a brain freeze.

Can anyone please guide me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try, this is in Java should be almost similar in python too

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement frameElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='mainFrame']"));
drive.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
```

SwitchTo defaultContent helps bring in focus properly, and later we can switch to the desired frame in the window.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@ name='mainFrame']")));
```

//perform operation which you want to perform on web elements present inside the frame(mainFrame), once you finish your operation come back to default

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```